# Why can't I retain this selection box's value? ([ ] brackets in select box name and ID)

Tags: php, magento, post

Please bear with me, my apologies if this post is too long...

I'm attempting to build a custom advanced search form within Magento. Basically, I have a bunch of select boxes and the selected values correspond with my Magento product attribute values and append to the URL, so if you had a selection box like this:

```
<select name="diameterange" id="diameterange">

      <option value=''<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['diameterange']=='all'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>all</option>
      <option value='15'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['diameterange']=='15'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Small</option>
      <option value='14'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['diameterange']=='14'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Medium</option>
      <option value='13'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['diameterange']=='13'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Large</option>
```

And you chose "Small", the URL would result in:

`http://mymagento.com/catalogsearch/advancedsearch/result/?diameterange=15`

You can see I'm echoing the values so that when the results page is loaded, the user sees the same search form with their selections pre-selected, above their new search results. This all works fine and dandy except for one attribute in particular - `price[from]`.

Here is the code for my `price[from]` selection box:

```
<select name="price[from]" id="price[from]">

      <option value=''<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['price[from]']==''?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>from (all)</option>

      <option value='100'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['price[from]']=='100'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>from $100</option>

      <option value='200'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['price[from]']=='200'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>from $200</option>

      <option value='300'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['price[from]']=='300'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>from $300</option>

      <option value='400'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['price[from]']=='400'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>from $400</option>

      <option value='500'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['price[from]']=='500'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>from $500</option>

      <option value='600'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['price[from]']=='600'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>from $600</option>

      <option value='700'<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['price[from]']=='700'?'selected="selected"':''; ?>>from $700+</option>

  </select>
```

This box and its selected value works correctly as far as the URL appending goes, and it will bring you the correct results, but I cannot get this selection box to remember its value like I can with the other attributes. So if a user has chosen a value in this box, his choice isn't pre-selected on the search form on the search results page.

I'm convinced this has something to do with the [ ] brackets in the select box's name and ID. How can I echo the selected choice for this particular box?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be probably be

```
$_SESSION['post']['price']['from']
```

instead. You can verify by doing a `var_dump($_SESSION['post'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of how you translate your $_POST into the session, but maybe you want to try changing `$_SESSION['post']['price[from]']` into `$_SESSION['post']['price']['from']`

Comment: Fabrizio, your answer worked, I've already 'checked' Marc's answer but I upvoted you... thanks!